# dropdownlist selected value confused me?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, webforms

I have asp.net page dropdownlist and button when choose my group from dropdownlist
and click button  then button send selected value (group-id) via query string
then page view group detail based on id in query string this happens the first time
but when I change group from dropdownlist the query string still has the last id
and my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) FillList();

    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        FillData();
        div_General.Visible = true;
        div_Special.Visible = true;
        dropdownlist1 .SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["id"];
    }
}

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dropdownlist1 .SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        par_ErrorMessage.InnerText = "choose group first  ...";
        par_ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    }
    else Response.Redirect("Authority.aspx?id=" + dropdownlist1.SelectedValue);
}
```

I figured the problem in this when I click button and suppose that new value in
dropdownlist page life cycle go to page load first and in this code

```
  dropdownlist1 .SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Return selected value to the last one before read it from button1_click

my FillList Method

```
     private void FillList()
{
    oGroup = new Cls_Groups();
    cmb_Group.DataSource = oGroup.LoadGroups();
    cmb_Group.DataBind();

    cmb_Group.Items.Insert(0, "-- اختر مما يلي --");
}
```

Please, I need help

Comment: is `FillList()` method for assign data-source to dropdown ?

Comment: private void FillList()
    {
        oGroup = new Cls_Groups();
        cmb_Group.DataSource = oGroup.LoadGroups();
        cmb_Group.DataBind();

        cmb_Group.Items.Insert(0, "-- choose group --");
    }

Comment: The "." on your keyboard works (you wrote "asp.net"). Please use that same "." to delimit sentences - that makes it easier to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Select Value for Drop Down after **Page Load** Event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack) 
      {
        FillList();
        Viewstate["id"] = Request.QueryString["id"];
         if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
           {
            FillData();
            div_General.Visible = true;
            div_Special.Visible = true;

           }
      }
}
```

Now in **Page_PreRender** you can Select Value in dropdown like this:-

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
   if (ViewState["id"] != null)
      {
          dropdownlist1 .SelectedValue = ViewState["id"].ToString();
       }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Please check with Updated Code

Comment: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 thanksssssssssss it works now

Comment: sorry but require 15 reputation and i don't have and know it

Answer (score 1):

One work around

create a hidden field(hiddenfield1) in your aspx page and make this changes in your page_Load method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) FillList();

    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        FillData();
        div_General.Visible = true;
        div_Special.Visible = true;
        hiddenfield1.Value =  dropdownlist1.SelectedValue.text;
    }
}
```

No in your aspx page within your body tage register onload function as on_loadabc()

Now within this function do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function on_loadabc(){

var dd = document.getElementById('<%=dropdownlist1.ClientId %>');
var hdnfield = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenfield1.ClientId %>');
for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
    if (dd.options[i].text === hdnfield.value ) {
        dd.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}


}
</script>
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you make mistake to drop down `filllist();` method

you call `FillList()` method when page `isnotpostback` 
but when you are doing redirect when user change dropdown selection 
so of course that time not happen `postback`  so you `need to fill dropdown list again`

```
if (!IsPostBack) FillList();

    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        FillData();
        div_General.Visible = true;
        div_Special.Visible = true;
         FillList();
        dropdownlist1 .SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["id"];
    }
```